# YouTube API - playlist returning invalid hangout videos

Tags: youtube-api

Using the standard/example code provided by Google for the YouTube API in order to display the list of videos found on a channel, I am getting lots of invalid and non-existent videos returned back. They appear to have been created by On Air Hangout events (for which, the "Start Broadcast" button was never pressed and instead the event was just cancelled).

```
$channelsResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels("contentDetails", array(
```

"mine" => "true",
));

foreach ($channelsResponse["items"] as $channel) {

```
$uploadsListId = $channel["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["uploads"];

$playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems("snippet", array(
    "playlistId" => $uploadsListId,
    "maxResults" => 50
));

echo "<h3>Videos in list $uploadsListId</h3><ul>";

foreach ($playlistItemsResponse["items"] as $playlistItem) {

    echo $playlistItem["snippet"]["title"] . " (" . $playlistItem["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"] . ")<br>";
    echo "<img src=" . $playlistItem["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["default"]["url"] . "><br>";
    echo "<br><br>";

}

echo "</ul>";
```

}

The invalid videos being returned do NOT show up when actually going into my YouTube account in the Video Manager. It's like they are ghost listings. Of course, actually conducting an On Air Hangout will cause the video to be archived in YouTube and show up on the list as normal. But it appears there is a bug that's causing cancelled events to show up to... with no way to filer for them, delete them, or prevent them from being returned. Help!!!

Comment: Please fill bug reports in issue tracker and let me know. Also please give an example playlist to reproduce the error. Stackoverflow is only for programming questions.  https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report)

Comment: I have done so at https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5333 -- If anyone else is aware of a solution, please let me know!

Comment: Please give a playlist id, or user channel that this is occurring so we can reproduce this.

Comment: The example with my own account are the videos in list:

UUA3V2k4hnXKECF98ATu_P_w

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with API explorer? https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlists.list

Comment: No, I can't get the API explorer to work at all, but am not using it in the first place. I am using the example code provided by Google at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#retrieve_my_uploads, and then simply updating the client ID/secret and library path.

Comment: There is no channel with this id.